# Using WPF in Unity3d

Tags: wpf, unity-game-engine

I have a simple game I developed in WPF. Can I take the Xaml file of my Mainwindow and put in a Unity3d project? I'm very new to Unity and it's a bit hard for me to close the gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not use WPF within Unity. Unity supports a subset of the .Net framework which can be viewed here

http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html

WPF is part of the System.Windows namespace, which is absent from that list.